# MongoDB regex reverse

Tags: regex, performance, mongodb

Ok, I know, there was a similar question on this site, but it's 2 years old, so the situation can be different now.

I have some documents with stored regular expressions, just like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
    regex: /^some_regex.*$/
}
```

So I've got an input string and I need to find all the documents, where regex matches the string.

The only way to solve the problem I know, is $where operator usage, but it's not a solution I'm looking for, because $where is very, very slow. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such an opportunity in Mongo. `$where` operator is the only way to perform this server-side.